Singular Spectrum Analysis Decomposition on single input signal using PyTS module
I read this paper and was curious to apply it on a single-channel audio recording of mixed sources. It is about Singular Spectrum Analysis (SSA).
The paper mentions that a key component of the proposed technique is to change the mixture into pseudo-Multiple-Input-Multiple-Output (MIMO) mode with SSA decomposition, and then each source signal is separated via a fast algorithm of blind source separation.
This is something I wanted to try myself but I am unfamiliar with the python package PyTS's SSA-method and SSA. The audio contains speech and background noise, so I would argue an expansion of the original time-series signal to two signals,

X = X_1 + X_2, 

would be a good starting point to create the input to Blind Source Separation (BSS)-method. Is this possible?

Please spell out acronyms.  Not everyone on CrossValidated is a native English speaker and acronyms can be especially tricky. (For these ... well I am a native English speaker and I'm not sure what SSA is. Nor MIMO. Nor BBS,

Thanks for pointing that out. Question is updated.
